I'm working on a project to recognize a cell phone on HM-10 using flutter and HM-10
I created an app that advertises BLE through flutter.
I used flutter_bluetooth_serial library.
I confirmed that advertising was working well through the
"I/BLE Peripheral state (22874): advertising"
message in the flutter log.
But I don't know how to recognize my phone on HM-10
This is my arduino code.
Response to AT is OK.
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>

    SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3); // RX, TX

    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);
      mySerial.begin(9600);

      Serial.println("Starting BLE scan...");
      mySerial.println("AT"); 

      delay(1000);
      mySerial.println("AT+IMME0");
      delay(1000);
      mySerial.println("AT+ROLE1"); 
      delay(1000);
      mySerial.println("AT+DISC?");
    }

    void loop() {
      if (mySerial.available()) {
        String response = mySerial.readString();
        Serial.println(response);

        int nameIndex = response.indexOf("+NAME:");
        if (nameIndex >= 0) {
          String deviceName = response.substring(nameIndex + 6);
          deviceName.trim();
          Serial.println("Device Found: " + deviceName);
        }
      }
    }



I believe there are possibly two main issues here:- firstly, flutter_bluetooth_serial is a classic Bluetooth library and therefore will not be scanned by BLE central devices. You might want to consider using a BLE library instead (e.g. flutter_blue, flutter_reactive_ble). I don't have much experience with flutter, so I would double check if BLE peripheral is supported first. For prototyping, you can simply use the nRF Connect app to get your device to act as a BLE peripheral.
Secondly, some HM-10 documentation seem to imply that you need to do an AT+RESET before the BLE role change takes effect. I would try that in your code before attempting to discover BLE peripherals.
Below are some references:-

HM-10 BLE guide
flutter_bluetooth_serial documentation
flutter_blue documentation
flutter_reactive_ble library

